# possible to load the latest available datapoint and discard the rest in Druid?

Tags: druid

Consider raw events (alpha set in Druid parlance) of the form `timestamp | compoundId | dimension 1 | dimension 2 | metric 1 | metric 2`

Normally in Druid data can be loaded in Realtime nodes and historic nodes based on some rules. These rules seem to be related to time-ranges. E.g.:

- load the last day of data on boxes A
- load the last week (except last day) on boxes B
- keep the rest in deep storage but don't load segments.

In contrast I want to support the use-case of:

- load the last event for each given `compoundId` on boxes A. Regardless if that last event happened to be loaded today or yesterday.

Is this possible?

Alternatively, if the above is not possible, I figured it would perhaps be possible as a workaround to create a betaset (finest granulation level as follows):

Given an alphaset with schema as defined above, create a betaset so that:

- all events for a given `compoundId` are rolled-up.
- `metric1` and `metric2` are set to the metrics from the last occurring (largest timestamp) event.

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the [first and last aggregators](https://github.com/druid-io/druid/pull/3566) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Any docs on that already? This seems to support the second usecase I described no?

Comment: a nevermind. Found the docs/rationale [here](https://github.com/druid-io/druid/issues/2845). Thanks

Comment: @Geert-Jan here is the doc [link](https://github.com/druid-io/druid/blob/master/docs/content/querying/aggregations.md)